# How to convert binary to hexadecimal using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, hex

which is the easiest way that i can convert binary number into a hexadecimal number using latest python3?

i tried to convert a binary to number into a hexadecimal using `hex()` function. but it runs into few errors.

The code that i tried -:

```
choice = input("Enter Your Binary Number: ")

def binaryToHex(num):
    answer = hex(num)
    return(num)
    
print(binaryToHex(choice))
```

error that i faced :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\#Programming\Python\Number System Converter 0.1V\test.py", line 83, in <module>
    print(binaryToHex(choice))
  File "e:\#Programming\Python\Number System Converter 0.1V\test.py", line 80, in binaryToHex
    answer = hex(num)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

EXAMPLE-:

- 111 --> 7
- 1010101011 --> 2AB

Comment: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-convert-a-binary-string-to-a-hexadecimal-string-in-python

Comment: Show what you tried.  Show the "errors".  The example you've given shows valid conversions from binary to hex, so it's unclear what the problem is here.

Comment: don't worry. i solved it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `int` to convert a string of digits to an integer.  Use `hex` to convert that integer back to a hex string.

```
>>> hex(int('111', 2))
'0x7'
>>> hex(int('1010101011', 2))
'0x2ab'
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
# Python code to convert from Binary
# to Hexadecimal using int() and hex()
def binToHexa(n):
    
    # convert binary to int
    num = int(str(n), 2)
      
    # convert int to hexadecimal
    hex_num = hex(num)
    return(hex_num)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the Hex inbuilt function of Python 3. you can use this code too.

binary_string = input("enter binary number: ")

decimal_representation = int(binary_string, 2)
hexadecimal_string = hex(decimal_representation)

print("your hexadecimal string is: ",hexadecimal_string)

Answer (score 0):

### Method:

- Considering you need `'2AB'` instead of `'0x2ab'`.

```
>>> Hex=lambda num,base:hex(int(num,base))[2:].upper()
>>> Hex('111',2)
'7'
>>> Hex('1010101011',2)
'2AB'
```